# How to Export Whole Database with Data Inside

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can Generate Create Scripts of my database in MS Sql Server Management Studio. But I need to move the database to a shared server with all the data in it.

Since I don't have full admin rights, I can not backup/restore .bak files or attach there. Is there any way to generate "Insert" queries which insert all of the data when I run them after create queries.

Comment: I just found the answer. From Generate Script window, there is an option to save both data and scheme. Should this question be here for some others ? or some moderators can delete this

Comment: I dont think you can generate insert queries for data, these would potentially be mahoosive.  Have you considered doing a dts to a csv then restoring?  Depending on the complexity of the database this could be very tricky, back up and restore would save you ALOT of time, talk to your network admin :-)  The only other thing I can think of is a db compare tool, redgate do one but its not free.

Comment: really? I'm quite surprised at that, just ignore me then :-S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Here's how to do it:

1. Open up SSMS
2. Right-click on your database
3. Tasks -> Generate Scripts...
4. Choose the objects you want to script out (it sounds like you want the whole DB)
5. Under *Set Scripting Options* click the **Advanced** button
6. For the item **Types of data to script**, select ***Schema and data***